# Android webview: open a page wait 3 seconds then open another

Tags: java, android, webview, delay, wait

im trying to open a url, wait 3 seconds and then open another url, and so on... this is my code. the problem with this is: lets say runX=3 the webview will show the 3rd page after 9 seconds. im pretty sure its opening the pages but not showing them

```
    for(int loop = 0 ; loop < runX; loop++)
    {   
        WebView openURL = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView1);
            openURL.loadUrl(getURL());

            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
            }
    }
```

Comment: try using runnable post delay

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.sleep()` is **blocking the UI thread**, thus making it impossible for the `WebView` to draw anything with the URL you supplied.

As a general rule, `Thread.sleep()` on the UI thread is not a good idea.

You should use [`Handler.postDelayed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) instead. Get the three URLs, and post 3 Runnables with delays of (say) 3, 6, and 9.